# Crashed and cloud access to files

Tags: ubuntu-one

So, something happened to my 11.0 set up and I needed to format and re-install.

I am trying to look at the folders I sent to my Ubuntu one account that I set up but they do not show on another system I have. No backup folders are shown that I set up and could view form the old machine.

I thought that is why I would want to store folders on Ubuntu One so I could look at them from another machine and use them as back ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, that simply what I was looking for and found no simple expiation doing a Google search. I was also confused when the "services" tab sad to drag and drop any file or folder into the local Ubuntu folder that that would add them to my list. What it did was move the folder to the Ubuntu folder and that was not what I expected. I did not want my desktop or documents folder moved out of my home folder. Thanks for your help. How do I mark this as solved? Bob. – Bob Brazie yesterday